Is there anyway to set a variable in kamailio that is not reloading per sip and not constant?
I want to make a variable in Kamailio to change it in request_route in an if statement and if that variable is greater than something I return -255
is there any way?
FYI: after this, I want to use that variable from KEMI
I tried the AVP variables but they were not reliable.

If you need to be global in the context of a Kamailio instance, then the shared-memory-variable $shv(name) is one option, see pseudo-variables cookbook on Kamailio wiki site [1].
$shv(x) = "abc";
$shv(y) = 10;

An alternative would be to use a shared memory hash table and store an item in it for this purpose ($sht(htable=>key)), see htable module readme for more details [2].
$sht(t=>x) = $ru;
$sht(t=>y) = 10;

If you want it to be in the context of a Kamailio process (a Kamailio instance creates many processes), then look at $var(name) [3].
$var(x) = $ci;
$var(y) = 10;

[1] https://www.kamailio.org/wikidocs/cookbooks/devel/pseudovariables/#shvname-shared-memory-variables
[2] https://www.kamailio.org/docs/modules/stable/modules/htable.html
[3] https://www.kamailio.org/wikidocs/cookbooks/devel/pseudovariables/#varname-private-memory-variables-zero
